# AS3 character movement

Tags: actionscript-3

I am quite new to AS3 and am really enjoying learning it.
My problem is I need to move a character from one frame to another.

I know how to move him and make him go from one frame to the next scene by having him move with the arrow keys to a hit point, but I cant figure out how to do this below

If the character walks right to the end of the stage he should appear on the left of the next frame. If
he walks to the left of the stage he should appear on the right of the previous scene

Any help would be great, thanks guys.

Comment: What have you tried? Google your question and you get quite a few relevant results...

Answer (score 1):

You can add conditions in your key events handler:

```
// Here you set a new `x` value for the character
// If the redistration point is in the left top corner
if (myCharacter.x > stage.width)
    myCharacter.x = -myCharacter.width;
else if (myCharacter.x < -myCharacter.width)
    myCharacter.x = stage.width;
```

Comment: I got it to work. This is the code

What i would like to do is, instead of the character going to next scene. I would like the character to go to frames over 6 frames, does anyone know how I would be able to do that? thanks

Comment: You can hide the character for 6 frames and show when you need it, and where you need it.